# Displaying URL as label for a link with another URL

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, hyperlink

In my application I am looping through database items and display them in an list. Each item is a post with a title and when the post item is clicked it allows you to edit the item.  .

```
@foreach (var post in Model)
{
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("ViewPost", "Topic", new { id = post.PostID})">@Html.Raw(post.DisplayDescription)</a></li>

}
```

The problem I am having is when the title of the post is a URL, HTML.Raw will render it as a link

```
<a href="*URL HERE*" target="_Blank" rel="External">*URL HERE*</a>
```

This when clicked will obviously take you to the external URL and not my relative URL to edit the post.

Is there an easy way to strip the HTML or just display the URL as plain text from the database?

`@Html.DisplayFor` will display the whole anchor tag text but the link will work correctly.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add css to your anchor element to display url as plain text as below:

```
a{
   text-decoration: none;
}
```